# Android ProgressDialog not displayed correctly

Tags: android, progressdialog

In my app I use a ProgressDialog to show the user that some services are running. I start the ProgressDialog in my activity, but it is not displayed correctly. It is not started right away. Just when service is mostly done it pops up for a millisecond and dismisses again.

How does it work:

In my activity I have a button. When the button is clicked I start the ProgressDialog and call a AsyncTask for the service call. When the AsyncTask is done it broadcasts (!) the result back to the activity. The AsyncTask does not have direct access to the activity. The whole process works quit well. But not the ProgressDialog.

The ProgressDialog variable is a class member.

Comment: you need to include the code in your question so we could understand what is actually happening

Comment: if the `ProgressDialog.show()` is called in `OnPreExecute` then you are definitely running some blocking code on the `AsyncTask`. Just because you are using `AsyncTask` it doesn't mean that all the code is run in the background

Answer (score 0):

These are the 4 steps of `AsyncTask`, You should use the first one `onPreExecute()` and the last one `onPostExecute(Result)`, to show and dismiss your `ProgressDialog`

> When an asynchronous task is executed, the task goes through 4 steps:
>
> 1.- onPreExecute(), invoked on the UI thread before the task is executed. This step is normally used to setup the task, for instance
>   by showing a progress bar in the user interface.
>
> 2.- doInBackground(Params...), invoked on the background thread immediately after onPreExecute() finishes executing. This step is used
>   to perform background computation that can take a long time. The
>   parameters of the asynchronous task are passed to this step. The
>   result of the computation must be returned by this step and will be
>   passed back to the last step. This step can also use
>   publishProgress(Progress...) to publish one or more units of progress.
>   These values are published on the UI thread, in the
>   onProgressUpdate(Progress...) step.
>
> 3.- onProgressUpdate(Progress...), invoked on the UI thread after a call to publishProgress(Progress...). The timing of the execution is
>   undefined. This method is used to display any form of progress in the
>   user interface while the background computation is still executing.
>   For instance, it can be used to animate a progress bar or show logs in
>   a text field.
>
> 4.- onPostExecute(Result), invoked on the UI thread after the background computation finishes. The result of the background
>   computation is passed to this step as a parameter.

Info from: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: I call ProgressDialog.show() and ProgressDialog.dismiss() in my activity. So it is within the main thread. There is no handling in the doInBackground() method of the AsyncTask. What difference does is make to call show() in my activity or to call show() in the onPreExecute() method?

Comment: AsyncTask is a class which allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers. So It's a better way of programming to use this class using onPreExecute() for initialize this class and do all the stuff before starting the background operation in the UI thread and at the end use onPostExecute() to perform all the staff in the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create asyncTask object in your activity and call the execute() method. The CustomAsyncTask is the inner class.

`ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
 mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(PlayerView.this);
CustomAsyncTask asyncTask = new CustomAsyncTask();
    asyncTask.execute();`

```
private class CustomAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading");
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("please wait");
            mProgressDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<PlayerViewModel> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return //do yout doInBackground work here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void void) {
      //when your process completed hide the ProgressDialog
        mProgressDialog.hide();
    }
}
```

You have to do is that, start the progress dialog in the onPreExecute() method and hide the progressDialog in the onPostExecute method,Because both these methods are working on the main Thred.